# Is it possible to add two header rows in react-virtualized?

Tags: react-virtualized

Is it possible to add two header rows in react-virtualized just like in fixed-data-table? I would like to be able to have some of the columns in the first header row span a few columns to categorize the columns on the second row.

Answer (score 1):

`FlexTable` does not allow for custom header-row rendering. However you could disable the header entirely (using the `disableHeader` prop) and render your own "header" above a `FlexTable` (or `Grid`) body.

app.becontentking.com does something similar to this. They use a `Grid` for the body (so it virtualizes the rows of data) but they render their own header row above it (so they can more easily customize its appearance).